# Maven profile activation in interactive mode

Tags: maven, maven-profiles

I have a Maven project that has multiple modules, I want to include module only in version managment. This solution works for me.

```
<profiles>
  <profile>
    <id>version</id>
    <activation>
      <property>
        <name>newVersion</name>
      </property>
    </activation>
    <modules>
      <module>module-to-include</module>
    </modules>
  </profile>
</profiles>
<modules>
  <module>module-1</module>
  <module>module-2</module>
</modules>
```

It works only when passing `-DnewVerison=x.x.x` in mvn command line.
But in more complex cases, like setting version with interactive mode, or revert version, it does not work. any suggestions please?

Profile management must be in the pom file, Passing `-P` parameter in command line must be done implicitly.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it is not possible to enable profiles from anything other than the command line. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23496528/944849).