# unit tests in multi module maven project are skipped

Tags: java, maven, unit-testing, integration-testing, maven-module

**Scenario**: Multi-module Maven project

**Issue**: Unit tests are only running for a single module.

**Background**:
I'm attempting to separate my integration testing from unit testing.  To do this I've created two properties in my parent pom, **Root-module**, that disable unit tests and integration tests by default.

```
<maven.test.skip>true</maven.test.skip>
<maven.integration.test.skip>true</maven.integration.test.skip>
```

In my top-most module, **UI-module**, I've created two profiles, *dev* and *integration-test*.  *Dev* has unit tests enabled and *integration-test* has integrations enabled:

```
<profile>
....
<maven.test.skip>false</maven.test.skip>
</profile>
```

*Integration-test* works correctly.  The *dev* profile only runs the unit-tests for the **UI-module**, which is where the pom.xml is located that contains these profiles.

How can I enable unit tests for all modules?  Is the profile approach correct?  If so, why isn't the value applied to other modules?

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18874421/944849). You likely need to include the same profile, with the same activation block, in the module POMs you want to inherit the config.

Comment: I was afraid that might be the case and that makes me sad.

Comment: Me too. I spent the better part of day a while back trying to make this work before finally figuring out that the inheritance isn't there.