# maven parent POM profiles

Tags: java, maven, properties, pom.xml, maven-profiles

Does child projects inherit profiles (and their properties) either from parent POM or via parent's module declaration? Does declaring the profile of the same name in child POM override all the properties set in parent POM, or worse, will declaring any profile hide all the parent profiles? What is the best practice to cope with the situation, where multiple child modules should use common properties with a certain profile, but also define their proprietary properties for this specific profile?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Inheriting Maven profiles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3695394/inheriting-maven-profiles)

Comment: It shouldn't be too difficult to test this - have you created some simple POMs and tried to use profiles in the manner you suggest?